# Merging nearly identical, imperfectly overlapping line shapefiles (of railways)

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, overlapping-features, snapping

I have digitized and (imperfectly) georeferenced old railway maps in QGIS. In the figure below you see two of the resulting line shapefiles representing two different years. Due to poor georeferencing on the one hand and different degrees of detail and quality of the maps, the overlap between lines representing the same railway is not perfect.

My aim is to obtain a shapefile where different railway sections have a construction year attribute. If I had perfectly overlapping rails, I could just intersect the baseline shapefile with preceding shapefiles to determine which sections were added when.

I can improve the georeferencing to some extent but how would I go about achieving this with the shapefiles at hand?

Some ideas I had:

- creating buffers around the lines, keeping what does not overlap and running a spatial join on the baseline shapefile
- removing line segments in one shapefile that are close to a line segment in the other shapefile and running a spatial join between the remainder and the baseline

I am worried that following the first approach will get the start and end the segments wrong. I don't know how to implement the second approach but it might suffer the same problem.

[image: Two line shapefiles representing mostly the same network but with imperfect overlap]

Comment: Tough task. Maybe join attributes by nearest? Maybe just use midpoints to join to avoid wrong assignments at crossings. Or snap geometries to layer? Still, i don't think youll get this done without manual work. Do both rails share a common name? Then you could join by distance and attribute condition. Or use the main angle of a line as condition. Just some ideas but no answer...

Comment: Thanks, sounds like join by nearest might help, I'll give that a try! Sadly I have no attributes to join on, I was only able to extract the lines (from scans of old railway maps).